# Error on scaffolding identity in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I created a basic CRUD operation in my application which have `applicationDbContext` as its `Dbcontext` class and I added the `applicationDbContext` it to the service container in `program.cs` file.

I also did scaffolding identity which I use the same `applicationDbContext` class as the `DbContext` class and the `applicationDbContext` for the scaffolding identity was also added automatically to the service container

Now, I noticed the `applicationDbContext` in the service container are conflicting each other, in other word it's only the `applicationDbContext` for the scaffolded identity that was able to validate, the `applicationDbContext` for the CRUD operation failed to validate and I run into the error below

> AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BulkyBook.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: BulkyBook.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve service for type 'BulkyBook.DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'BulkyBook.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork'.)

Here's the code:

```
// ApplicationDbContext for the CRUD operation 
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext   
{
   public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
   {
   }

   public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
   public DbSet<CoverType> CoverType { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

// ApplicationDbContext for the scaffolded identity
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling  base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConection")));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

var app = builder.Build();
```

Please I really need help with these errors, what can I do to resolve them?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the new `applicationdbContext` that got generated during the scaffolding, solve the problem.
Two *applicationdbcontext* can not be present in a single project.